# regular expression for run files

Tags: c#, windows

in my application i use

```
ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
ManagementBaseObject e = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
string name = ((ManagementBaseObject)e["TargetInstance"])["Name"].ToString();
```

"name" is now "runfile.exe".
when i use it later on, i need it without the ending: ".exe", so i used

`name = Regex.Replace(name, ".exe", "");`

my questione is, could there be run files which do not end in ".exe"? what about ".bat"? i am only concerned about files the user run himself to load the program, not installations and settings.
could there be ".exe" in the middle of a run file name?
if someone could just write a regular expression for run files on windows it would be grate. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)` method.

MSDN Link: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)